# C++ "typeid" error : operator not allowed in a constant expression

Tags: c++, types, enums

I am new to C++. I want to construct a class that holds the type information and the value of an object, and this is what I did:

```
#include <typeinfo>
enum My_Type {
    MyInteger = typeid(int);       //ERROR
    MyDuoble = typeid(double);     //ERROR
    MyBoolean = typeid(boolean);   //ERROR
    MyString = typeid(char *);     //ERROR
}

template <typename T>
MyClass {
    MyClass(T& Value) {
        value = Value;
        t = typeid(T);
    }

    T value;
    My_Type t;
}
```

This gives me an error **"this operator is not allowed in a constant expression"** when I try assigning integers to my Enum type..

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a more elegant way to achieve what I'm trying to do, instead of using typeid()?

Thanks

Comment: `typeid` does not return an integral constant.

Comment: @chris so is there a way to get a unique integer value of a c++ type?

Comment: Not that I know of. What are you planning to do with this class?

Comment: @chris Basically retrieving a data from a database and storing the type and value of a Field

Comment: C++ is not well-suited to reflection.

Comment: I doubt if such an operation would be feasible. You could always take two source files whose classes "used" to have the same number, and add them to the same project. As @chris said, what are you *really* doing, so we don't fall into the XY Problem.

Comment: You should look into `boost::variant` to see how such problems are handled properly

Comment: Why do you want to know the id of a type ? Generally speaking, you should use the type itself, not manipulate it through its id (which is not possible in standard C++ anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an overloaded function to convert a set of known types to integers:

```
int id_of_type( int    ) { return 1; }
int id_of_type( double ) { return 2; }
int id_of_type( bool   ) { return 3; }
int id_of_type( char * ) { return 4; }
```

A strictly compile-time type based way is a template:

```
template< typename T > struct id_of_type_t; // template declaration

// template instantiations for each type
template<> struct id_of_type_t< int    > { static const int value = 1; };
template<> struct id_of_type_t< double > { static const int value = 2; };
template<> struct id_of_type_t< bool   > { static const int value = 3; };
template<> struct id_of_type_t< char * > { static const int value = 4; };

// helper function that is slightly prettier to use
template< typename T >
inline int id_of_type( void )
{
    return id_of_type_t< T >::value;
}

// get the id by passed value type
template< typename T > void show_id( T )
{
    cout << id_of_type_t< T >::value << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using c++11, you can get the unique hash_code for each type you use. Typeid produces a [type_info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) object and cppreference has a good [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code) of how you can make use of this.